# PasteSpecial in PowerPoint VBA gies Member Not Found error

Tags: vba, powerpoint, paste

I am looking at copying certain objects (shapes, graphs) on Powerpoint and then pasting them back as Images.

I am able to select and paste back objects fine, but when I write the same syntax for PasteSpecial, Powerpoint throws up the error:
Compile Error: Member or data member not found

```
Sub AddPic()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
    Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=100, Height:=200)

shp.Copy

shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlue
sld.Shapes.Paste
End Sub
```

The above works as expected.

Now if I replace sld.Shapes.Paste with PasteSpecial, I get this the above error.

```
Sub AddPic()

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
    Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=100, Height:=200)
shp.Copy  
shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlue

'sld.Shapes.Paste

sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

[Error while using PasteSpecial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOXLL.png)

Has anyone faced a similar issue? Thank you in advance for your help.
I am using the latest Powerpoint for Mac.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce, but I'm on Windows. Maybe try to give it some time, some `DoEvents`?

Comment: Is the second code working fine on Windows?
Looking up DoEvents - not sure yet how it would be used in this case?

Comment: yes it is working for me.

Comment: Thank you for the response. i see this is running fine on my windows. So this appears to a Mac specific issue.